# Macbook Pro 15" Mid 2010 Keycap problem

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, repair

I am having a problem with my "a" key sticking. The key is clean, but I looked at some diagrams and compared them to my key, and it seems that the top pin on the scissor mechanism has snapped off or is otherwise gone.

I would like to replace just the faulty key. Is that possible? Do I need to replace the keyboard assembly as well?

Where can I find a replacement?

I looked at iFixit and they did not have the part. I also looked on PowerbookMedic and they had the entire top keyboard assembly, but I don't want to have to go that route if there is only one faulty key.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe go to your local apple store (or repair center).
They often have spare keys around from broken keyboards and/or topcases.
Otherwise check ebay (make sure it's the same model. Apple changed the mechanism behind they keys 2 or 3 times afaik)